# Merge 3 Dataframes into 1 to create 1 specific column in Excel using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns in my dataframes that I want to join together into one column. Unfortunately, when I try to merge all three dataframes that contain each column, they just create 3 seperate columns instead of one column. Below is my code, a picture of the result, and my three seperate workbooks in Excel I pasted here. I'm not getting errors when I run the code but it's not yielding the result I was hoping for. I tried concatenating also but I still just end up with three separate columns instead of one (as seen from the picture). The arrows from the picture signify that I want to add the data from Columns P and Q along with O, which would yield a very long text within the column. That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Is this possible to do?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

# Read excel files
df_main = pd.read_excel('/Users/admin/Documents/Product_Key.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df_one = pd.read_excel('/Users/admin/Documents/Product1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols="A:E")
df_two = pd.read_excel('/Users/admin/Documents/Product2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols="A:E")

# Sets columns from excel file documents within dataframes
df_main['new_main'] = df_main['Label'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['Type'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['Serial ID'].astype(str) \
                    + '_' + df_main['Weight'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['Row'].astype(str)
df_one['new_one'] = df_one['Label'].astype(str) + '_' + df_one['Type'].astype(str) + '_' + df_one['Serial ID'].astype(str) \
                    + '_' + df_one['Weight'].astype(str) + '_' + df_one['Row'].astype(str)
df_two['new_two'] = df_two['Label'].astype(str) + '_' + df_two['Type'].astype(str) + '_' + df_two['Serial ID'].astype(str) \
                    + '_' + df_two['Weight'].astype(str) + '_' + df_two['Row'].astype(str)

df_main['new_one'] = df_main['Label'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['Type'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['Serial ID'].astype(str) \
                    + '_' + df_main['Weight'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['Row'].astype(str)
df_main['new_two'] = df_main['True Label'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['True Type'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['True Serial ID'].astype(str) \
                     + '_' + df_main['True Weight'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['True Row'].astype(str)

# Merges all three dataframes into one dataframe (main)
df_combine = df_main.merge(df_main['new_one'], on='new_one').merge(df_main['new_two'], on='new_two')

# Prints to excel
df_combine.to_excel('/Users/admin/Documents/New_Product_Key.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)
```

Product1 (Table 1)

+----------+-------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+---------+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| Label    | Type  | Serial ID | Weight | Row | Color  | Time #  | Lace |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+----------+-------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+---------+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| Man-o    | chase | 535       | 34     | 1   | Red    | 2983je  | 432  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Man-o    | chase | 535       | 23     | 2   | Blue   | 329ign  | 234  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Man-o    | chase | 535       | 11     | 3   | Green  | q3irj4  | 234  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Medu     | yoto  | 535       | 23     | 1   | Red    | 43io4i  | 34   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Medu     | yoto  | 535       | 22     | 2   | Blue   | 3494ii  | 34   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Medu     | yoto  | 535       | 43     | 3   | Green  | 34ioj3  | 34   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Cheeturo | timoq | 8439      | 12     | 1   | Orange | 29urwf  | 3    |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Cheeturo | timoq | 8439      | 15     | 2   | Red    | 29nwef  | 4    |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Cheeturo | timoq | 8439      | 24     | 3   | Blue   | 2934u   | 3    |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Cheeturo | timoq | 8439      | 34     | 4   | Green  | 924oiun | 4    |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Cod-4    | zulus | 904       | 12     | 1   | Red    | 49o23i  | 633  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Cod-4    | zulus | 904       | 24     | 2   | Blue   | 29i4ou  | 50   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Cod-4    | zulus | 904       | 34     | 3   | Green  | 9oin    | 6363 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| ZZ       | sog   | 1312      | 73     | 1   | Red    | 29i34   | 65   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| ZZ       | sog   | 1312      | 31     | 2   | Blue   | 21oui4e | 43   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| ZZ       | sog   | 1312      | 65     | 3   | Yellow | 4iuo4   | 65   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+----------+-------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+---------+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+

Product2 (Table 2)

+--------+-------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+---------+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| Label  | Type  | Serial ID | Weight | Row | Color  | Time #  | Lace |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--------+-------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+---------+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| Idit   | chase | 64        | 431    | 1   | Cream  | 2983je  | 10   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Idit   | chase | 64        | 453    | 2   | Red    | 329ign  | 10   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Idit   | chase | 64        | 4353   | 3   | Orange | q3irj4  | 10   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Makopp | yoto  | 64        | 435    | 1   | Red    | 43io4i  | 20   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Makopp | yoto  | 64        | 536    | 2   | Blue   | 3494ii  | 20   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Makopp | yoto  | 64        | 457    | 3   | Cream  | 34ioj3  | 20   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sharp  | timoq | 954       | 34     | 1   | Orange | 29urwf  | 34   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sharp  | timoq | 954       | 643    | 2   | Red    | 29nwef  | 34   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sharp  | timoq | 954       | 7      | 3   | Cyan   | 2934u   | 34   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sharp  | timoq | 954       | 5443   | 4   | Black  | 924oiun | 34   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Yngo   | zulus | 845       | 754    | 1   | White  | 49o23i  | 50   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Yngo   | zulus | 845       | 846    | 2   | Neon   | 29i4ou  | 50   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Yngo   | zulus | 845       | 4      | 3   | Green  | 9oin    | 50   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| pao    | sog   | 524       | 6      | 1   | Blue   | 29i34   | 65   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| pao    | sog   | 524       | 45     | 2   | Blue   | 21oui4e | 65   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| pao    | sog   | 524       | 45     | 3   | Yellow | 4iuo4   | 65   |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--------+-------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+---------+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+

Product_Key (Table 3)

+-----------+-------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+---------+------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+----------+------------+
| Label     | Type  | Serial ID | Weight | Row | Color  | Time #  | Lace | True Label | True Type | True Serial ID | True Weight | True Row | True Color |
+-----------+-------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+---------+------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+----------+------------+
| Rot-dt    | chase | 13423     | 10     | 1   | Red    | 2983je  | 10   | Rot-dt     | chase     | 8944           | 27          | 1        | Purple     |
| Rot-dt    | chase | 13423     | 23     | 2   | Blue   | 329ign  | 10   | Rot-dt     | chase     | 8944           | 76          | 2        | Cyan       |
| Rot-dt    | chase | 13423     | 11     | 3   | Green  | q3irj4  | 10   | Rot-dt     | chase     | 8944           | 34          | 3        | Yellow     |
| Mako      | yoto  | 13423     | 23     | 1   | Red    | 43io4i  | 20   | Mako       | yoto      | 3453           | 7           | 1        | Purple     |
| Mako      | yoto  | 13423     | 22     | 2   | Blue   | 3494ii  | 20   | Mako       | yoto      | 3453           | 33          | 2        | Blue       |
| Mako      | yoto  | 13423     | 10     | 3   | Green  | 34ioj3  | 20   | Mako       | yoto      | 3453           | 63          | 3        | White      |
| Sharpedge | timoq | 43847     | 12     | 1   | Orange | 29urwf  | 34   | Sharpedge  | timoq     | 1154           | 23          | 1        | Purple     |
| Sharpedge | timoq | 43847     | 15     | 2   | Red    | 29nwef  | 34   | Sharpedge  | timoq     | 1154           | 43          | 2        | Cyan       |
| Sharpedge | timoq | 43847     | 24     | 3   | Blue   | 2934u   | 34   | Sharpedge  | timoq     | 1154           | 6           | 3        | White      |
| Sharpedge | timoq | 43847     | 30     | 4   | Green  | 924oiun | 34   | Sharpedge  | timoq     | 1154           | 32          | 4        | Green      |
| Cod-3     | zulus | 4384      | 12     | 1   | Red    | 49o23i  | 50   | Cod-3      | zulus     | 7342           | 55          | 1        | Purple     |
| Cod-3     | zulus | 4384      | 24     | 2   | Blue   | 29i4ou  | 50   | Cod-3      | zulus     | 7342           | 64          | 2        | Blue       |
| Cod-3     | zulus | 4384      | 12     | 3   | Green  | 9oin    | 50   | Cod-3      | zulus     | 7342           | 23          | 3        | Yellow     |
| Nin2B     | sog   | 25423     | 11     | 1   | Red    | 29i34   | 65   | Nin2B      | sog       | 3463           | 36          | 1        | Cyan       |
| Nin2B     | sog   | 25423     | 31     | 2   | Blue   | 21oui4e | 65   | Nin2B      | sog       | 3463           | 22          | 2        | Purple     |
| Nin2B     | sog   | 25423     | 24     | 3   | Yellow | 4iuo4   | 65   | Nin2B      | sog       | 3463           | 43          | 3        | Green      |
+-----------+-------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+---------+------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+----------+------------+

Answer (score 0):

The P and Q columns were concatenated using the below code and added to column O. This code was used to replace the line where I attempted to merge the dataframes.

```
df_main['Main ID'] = df_main['new_main'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['new_one'].astype(str) + '_' + df_main['new_two'].astype(str)
```